# Almost half crazy vs Almost half sane

Tags: syntax, semantics, lexical-semantics, syntax-trees

Forgive me if it is not the right place to ask this question in SE sites. I am mostly active on SO but I thought it might be a better fit here.

I enrolled in a class this semester and there was a question asked that I could not answer. Here it is:

> In terms of semantics, "crazy" does not mean the same as "sane".
>
> The phrase "half crazy" means the same as "half sane".
>
> The phrase "almost half crazy" does not mean the same as "almost half
>   sane".
>
> If we read their semantics off of trees compositionally from the way
>   they are combined, what kind of tree structures can we assume for
>   them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Trees are not going to solve the problem. This is not a syntactic issue; it's **semantic**.
Note, no syntax up my sleeve in the following.

*`Sane` ... `Crazy`* represents a semantic cline, with *sane* and *crazy* at opposite poles.

> (They can both be used with *absolutely*, which can only modify a polar adjective:
>
> - *He's absolutely sane/crazy.*
> - *It's absolutely freezing/broiling outside* **vs** **It's absolutely hot/warm/tepid/cool/cold outside.*)

The key word is *almost*, which is a **vector** quantity;
i.e, it points not only to a quantity on a cline, but a **direction** as well.

> A simple example is the difference between *Few people attended* and *A few people attended*.  The same absolute numbers may well be reported by both, but *few* is negative, while *a few* is positive.
>   This orientation refers to expectations or hopes on the part of the speaker.
>
> *Few people* means '**fewer** than hoped/expected';
>   *a few people* means '**more** than hoped/expected'.

---

*Almost* means 'close to, but lower than, some clinal value'.
*Half sane* and *half crazy* both refer to the midpoint on the cline,
i.e, they **do** point to the same position on the cline.
**But** they refer to opposite directions on the cline.

*Half sane* means 'a sanity value of .5'; i.e, *sane* is UP, *crazy* is DOWN on the cline.
*Half crazy* means 'a craziness value of .5'; i.e, *crazy* is UP, *sane* is DOWN.

Since *almost* is always on the DOWN side of a cline position,
*almost half crazy* does not mean the same as *almost half sane*.
*Almost half crazy* announces a **craziness** value < .5, and thus a **sanity** value > .5.
This is saner than *almost half sane*, which announces a sanity value < .5.

Good luck doing this with syntax trees.

Comment: Why would one want to "assume a type of tree structure" for them (and btw, what is meant by "them")? Why not a spreadsheet structure or an energy field structure? Structures are invented by theoreticians for their own purposes, and may or may not be useful for describing any phenomenon. Tree-like structures are often useful for hierarchical or genetic models, but they're hardly universal.

Answer (score 1):

The question your teacher gave you has already been discussed by Barbara Partee in her introductory paper ‘Lexical Semantics and Compositionality’ (see reference at the end) - only she used *almost half empty* and *almost half full*. If we assume that the constituent structure of both expressions is as in (1), and also make the assumption in (2), the question then arises how come the two expressions differ in meaning.

> (1) [almost [half [crazy/sane]]]
>
> (2) The meaning of a complex expression is derived by combining the meaning
>      of each of its elements with that element with which it forms a constituent.

Adopting (2) means that according to (1), we derive the meaning of *almost half crazy* by first combining the meanings of *half* and *crazy* and then combining the meaning of *almost* with that of *half crazy*. Since *half crazy* has the same meaning as *half sane*, it’s not clear how *almost* gives one meaning when combined with the first and another meaning when combined with the second.

**One way** to solve the problem is to deny that the expressions *almost half crazy/sane* have the structure in (1) and assign them instead the constituent structure in (3), which is also given by the tree in (4).

> (3) [[almost half] [crazy/sane]]
>
> (4)
>
> [image]
>            [see tree on our website](http://contextors.com/examples/almost_half_crazy.html?ref=1023)

According to (3) and (4), in deriving the meanings of the expressions *almost half crazy/sane*, the meaning of *almost half* combines each time with another meaning, and therefore it is not surprising that the two final expressions differ in meaning.

**A second way** to solve the problem is to accept the constituent structure in (1), but to deny that *half crazy* and *half sane* have the same meaning. Maybe the meanings of *half crazy* and *half sane* always combine with some approximation/precision value, and when such value is not expressed it is taken to be the absolute precision value (the value expressed by *exactly*). We can now assume that the meanings of *half crazy* and *half sane* are such that they give the same meaning when combining with the meaning of *exactly* but not when combining with the meanings of other approximation/precision expressions (like *almost*).

**A third way** to solve the problem is to accept the constituent structure in (1), but to deny the principle expressed by (2). We can now assume that in deriving the meanings of *almost half crazy/sane*, the meaning of *almost* is combined with the meaning of *half*, even though it doesn’t form a constituent with this element.

**Reference:** *Invitation to Cognitive Science*, 2nd edition. Daniel Osherson, general editor; in Part I: *Language*, Lila Gleitman and Mark Liberman, eds. MIT Press, Cambridge 1995, pp. 311-360.